# In Scala how do I filter by reified types at runtime?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have a Scala collection that contains objects of different subtypes.

```
abstract class Base

class A extends Base

class B extends Base

val a1 = new A()
val a2 = new A()
val b = new B()
val s = List(a1, a2, b)
```

I'd like to filter out all the `A` objects or the `B` objects. I can do this easily if I know the object I want to filter on at compile time.

```
s.filter(_.isInstanceOf[A]) // Give me all the As
s.filter(_.isInstanceOf[B]) // Give me all the Bs
```

Can I do it if I only know the object type to filter on at runtime? I want to write a function like this.

```
def filterType(xs:List[Base], t) = xs.filter(_.isInstanceOf[t])
```

Where `t` indicates whether I want objects of type `A` or `B`.

Of course I can't actually write it this way because of type erasure. Is there an idiomatic Scala way to work around this using type tags? I've been reading the Scala type tag documentation and relevant StackOverflow posts, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has come up a few times.  Duplicate, anyone?

```
scala> trait Base
defined trait Base

scala> case class A(i: Int) extends Base 
defined class A

scala> case class B(i: Int) extends Base 
defined class B

scala> val vs = List(A(1), B(2), A(3))
vs: List[Product with Serializable with Base] = List(A(1), B(2), A(3))

scala> def f[T: reflect.ClassTag](vs: List[Base]) = vs collect { case x: T => x }
f: [T](vs: List[Base])(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])List[T]

scala> f[A](vs)
res0: List[A] = List(A(1), A(3))
```

Comment: An upvote for you, because I didn't realize `match` could take advantage of the `ClassTag`, and that really is key here.

Answer (score 1):

Type erasure will destroy any information in type parameters, but objects still know what class they belong to. Because of this, we cannot filter on arbitrary types, but we can filter by class or interface/trait. `ClassTag` is preferable to `TypeTag` here.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def filterType[T: ClassTag](xs: List[Base]) = xs.collect {
  case x: T => x
}
```

Which we can use like:

```
scala> filterType[B](s)
res29: List[B] = List(B@42096939)

scala> filterType[Base](s)
res30: List[Base] = List(A@8dbc09c, A@625f8cc7, B@42096939)
```

This method is safe at run-time if type `T` is not generic. If there was a `class C[T] extends Base` we could not safely filter on `C[String]`.

Comment: Looks like @wingedsubmariner, being winged, just beat me to it, though the pattern matcher obviates the isInstance test.

Comment: You are right, @som-snytt. I've cleaned up my answer to no longer use `isInstance` and `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner This is a great solution; I've tried to add type bounds to the function signature by replacing `[Base]` with `[_ >: T]`, the idea being to catch at compile time filter operations which in principle can never succeed (assuming the original list population hasn't been undermined). However the compiler doesn't reject them. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @satyagraha It probably just chooses `Any` as its `T`, which then makes it always type-check. I'm not sure how to do what you want easily.